# Greendroid - ActionBar with Seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, seekbar, greendroid

is it possible to add an [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) Widget to an GreenDroid ActionBar?

At the moment I have no idea how it could work, hope you can help me :)